# WP8 StackPanel Controls

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have a handful of `TextBlock`'s which I wish to group together, so that if one of them happens to contain a lot of text, the controls beneath it move down accordingly.

At the moment I have wrapped the `TextBlock`'s in a `<StackPanel>`, however, the controls are now widely seperated, vertically. How can I shorten the distance between them?

This is my code:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblCategoryTitle" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Category"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="29" Width="456" Margin="0,59,0,0" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblCategory" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="Category" Margin="0,88,10,428" />
    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblContactDetails" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="Contact Details" Margin="0,179,289,396" FontWeight="Bold">
        <TextBlock.Foreground>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}" />
        </TextBlock.Foreground>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblName" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name"
                Margin="0,211,10,364" />
    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblAddress" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="Address" Margin="0,243,10,332" />
    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblEmail" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Email"
                Margin="0,275,10,300" />
    <TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblTelephone" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="Telephone" Margin="0,307,10,268" />
</StackPanel>
```

I guess I should also ask if `StackPanel` is the right control for my requirement. What do you folks think?

Comment: Your margins are too large, they separate the controls between each other, it is not a absolute positioning anymore. Simply use `Margin="12,0,0,12"` for most cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got some pretty big margins there -- if you reduce the sizes of the margins, the text blocks will get a lot closer. You don't need to offset everything to the top (in fact, you *shouldn't*) as the stackpanel will treat the offset from the previous item in the `<StackPanel>`

Comment: Ah, silly me I forgot about those margins. Thank you very much Rowland.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your control to be widely separated, just reduce the margins. It looks like you forgot to adjust the margins after changing the type of panel.

For instance, for your last TextBlock:

```
<TextBlock Height="auto" TextAlignment="Left" x:Name="lblTelephone" TextWrapping="Wrap"
            Text="Telephone" Margin="0,307,10,268" />
```

The four numbers of the margin indicate respectively the left margin, top, right, bottom. So just reduce the second number and it should be fine.